# iphone sdk get actual size of image in bytes

Tags: ios, uiimage, image-size

How to get actual size of image ?

I am using

```
NSInteger actualSize  = CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage) * CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image.CGImage);
```

or

```
NSData *imageData2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
[imageData2 length];
```

but I don't get the actual size of image it is either larger of smaller compared to the size on the disk (as I am using simulator).

Is there any way to get actual size of the image?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (for iOS 6.0 or later and OS X 10.8):

```
NSLog(@"%@",[NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:imageData2.length countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile]);
```

**UPDATE:**

Question: Can you post code where you initialise your image?

Above solution did not work for you. Let's try something else. You could try to check directly image file size:

```
    NSError* error;
NSDictionary *fileDictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:mediaURL error: &error];
NSNumber *size = [fileDictionary objectForKey:NSFileSize];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when I used your code then I get the size of the image as 244 kb, but actual size on disk is 94 kb. But when I used the compression 0.9 for UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0); instead for 1.0 I got 96 kb which is quite close to actual size on disk. But I did not get consistent results when used another images. For jpg images sometimes results are good but not all times, for png found size is quite small compared to size on the disk.

Comment: Update answer. Can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon what you mean by "size".

- If you want the amount of memory used while the image is loaded into memory and used by the app, the bytes-per-row times height is the way to go. This captures the amount of memory used by the uncompressed pixel buffer while the image is actively used by the app.
- If you want the number of bytes used in persistent storage when you save the image (generally enjoying some compression), then grab the the original asset's `NSData` and examine its `length`. Note, though, if you load an image and then use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` with a quality of 1, you'll generally get a size a good deal larger than the original compressed file.

Bottom line, standard JPEG and PNG files enjoy some compression, but when the image is loaded into memory it is uncompressed. You can't generally infer the original file size from a `UIImage` object. You have to look at the original asset.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and editing my post. Actually I am working on a app which deals with emails. When a user sends an attachment in a mail then we will present them with different sizes of the attachment.